# Change text depending on selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've initialized an array with various prices. The prices correlate to a given size of an item, 10, 30, and 120. I've written a script to change the value of `#pricing` depending on the value of a dropdown.

*JS*

```
var prices = {
    '10' : '5',
    '30' : '10',
    '120' : '15'
};

function updPrix() {
    var key = $("#size").val();
    $("#pricing").text(prices[key]);
}
```

*HTML*

```
<strong>Price: <span id="pricing"></span></strong> <br/><br/>
<select id="size" name="size" required="required" onchange="updPrix();">
    <option selected="selected" value="" disabled="disabled">Size</option>
    <option value="10">10mL</option>
    <option value="30">30mL</option>
    <option value="120">120mL</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do anything. What am I missing here? It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, unless you're running the JS above within another function, either using `window.onload = function(){}` or `$(document).ready(function(){});` in which case `updPrix()` is no longer global and won't  work in your inline event handler.

If this is the case, remove the `onchange` attribute and account for it within your function:

```
function updPrix() {
    $("#size").on("change", function(){
        var key = $(this).val();            
        $("#pricing").text(prices[key]);
    });
}
```

Comment: The way I have it right now is the array is initialized in the page with `<script>` tags. The function itself is in a separate file I link to in the `<head>`. I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, I'm not too well versed with Jquery or JSON or etc, my functions are usually pretty plain.

Comment: 1) Have you taken a look at your browsers console? 2) Does the separate file only contain the above function or is there any other code?

Comment: Everything appears on the page as intended in View Source with the exception of `#pricing` not appearing or changing. The .js has a lot of functions, but nothing I could identify as interfering. My other scripts work great.

Comment: Can you put the code onto a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It's difficult to help without seeing all code. Because what you posted above is working for me as is: http://jsfiddle.net/3Adke/5/

Comment: Absolutely. http://jsfiddle.net/2QtR5/ I've included what my Java includes look like despite their redundancy with JSFiddle.

Comment: I see that you're linking to `jquery` after you link to your own file. In order to use `$("#pricing")` or anything else the library gives you you have to include it **before** using this in your own file. Try switching the order around first.

Comment: Noted. It still doesn't seem to work. Removing `<head>` entirely from my Fiddle doesn't seem to resolve it. I noticed you put the `prices` array in with the other JS and it does indeed work, however I need it in HTML so I can pass SQL entries to fill in the array. I used 5,10,15 as an example, when really they're dynamic from SQL.

Comment: It will work either way: http://jsfiddle.net/3Adke/6/ ... my only guess is that `updPrix()` is nested within another function. If you use an event attribute like `onchange` the function must be in the global scope and not contained within anything else. Aside from that, it's hard to help any further.

Answer (score -1):

you didn't get those values which are selected.Try this:

```
var key = $("#size :selected").val();
```